# The horrors of working with executables on windows

Tags: php, apache, exec, executable

I run an executable called **Test.exe** via `exec` which in turns runs Outlook.

I am able to run the Test.exe fine but I get the error:

`Rejected Safe Mode action : Microsoft Office Outlook.` in the windows event viewer.

If I run Test.exe myself via DOS it works fine and no errors. So its something to do with how PHP is running this exectuable. I've enabled apache to run as an admin account but the same thing happens.

What else should I be doing so that Apache can run the executable without any problems?

Comment: so it works from a command prompt but not from exec ?

Comment: @Khez thats right. Very strange.

Comment: just by chance, but have you tried shell_exec or system ? Just curious...

Comment: @Khez - good idea, but I just tried that and unfortunately it didn't work. However, I just got it to work by some fluke of creating a new admin account. Although, its working, I don't like things that "suddenly" just work without being solved. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works from the command line but not from the Apache process. Not surprisingly because Apache probably runs as a service, with a system account (Non-Desktop interactive).

If you reconfigure the service to run as a user with the right to logon locally and mark the service to be allowed 'Interaction with Desktop', I expect you **could** do this.

However, I'm at a total loss why anyone, at all, would want to start Outlook from a webserver application....

Comment: Apache is running as an admin account. If you specify this in the services window, you can't allow interaction with the desktop. Only when allowing apache to run as local user system is this option available. As far as my reasons for doing this, they are very good ones.

Comment: @Abs: 'good' no doubt [having a very special meaning that I was previously unaware of :)](http://www.frogstar.com/content/safewav) (btw: you repeat exactly the same points as I do about the service account; did that not solve your problem?)

Comment: lol, yes it eventually did but it was unusual that I had to create a new account and then it worked even though previous account I was using was an admin!

Comment: Cheers. I hope you enjoyed the linked audio snippet!

Comment: THANK YOU, I have been debugging this for FOUR hours now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sehe is right (but for some reason I cannot comment to his post, whatever...). Usually, you should access MS Office facilities via external code using specific OLE interfaces. You *never* use CreateProcess to start Outlook or Word from your program, it would be pointless because how can you control it after launching it?

I suggest you to check if you really need this, and if there's a more clean way to do it. You can try to create an external C#/VB.NET executable that performs all the automation you may need to do with Microsoft Outlook, indeed.

What is the actual scenario?

And, I don't like to correct people but if I don't, someone else will in the future and it'll be annoying. Don't say "via DOS" when you use a prompt under Windows. :D

Comment: the executable Test.exe is a C# console application that I wrote that gets stuff from Outlook and saves it to a file. There isn't really another way when others need to access this via the web. Is there?

Comment: OK, I see. I'm sorry I didn't realize you was already being using an intermediate executable. So the executable uses OLE automation to grab the data from Outlook?

Comment: no worries, I didn't make it clear that was what I was doing. I was trying to keep it simple. I have managed to solve the problem now by some fluke of creating a new windows account.

Comment: I see. If you want to tell me more, I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

i too am perplexed by would anyone would want to do this.

If you REALLY wanted to do this i guess you could run it as "start test.exe" or write a batch file that would run it. basically anything that would cause a different process to be the one actually launching the app.